# Pure rolling on accelerated plank

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

A sphere at rest is placed on a plank. After that plank starts accelerating. My doubt is that what is the direction of motion of sphere when the plank starts accelerating to the right?
It is given that a solid sphere of mass m placed on it, rests on a smooth horizontal plane.
Does friction present between those two